# How do I retrieve the sender number when using Twilio's messaging services with Copilot enabled?

Tags: ruby, twilio

I have a Twilio messaging service with Copilot and the sticky sender feature enabled.
I would like to view the phone number that Copilot assigns to my recipients when I send them a message.
With the Ruby client, I get a `MessageContext` object when I send a message, but it only has the
messaging service SID - the `from` method returns `nil`.

Currently, this is how I'm sending messages:

```rb
def send(from, to, message)
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

  client.api.account.messages.create(
    body: message,
    messaging_service_sid: from,
    to: to,
    status_callback: BASE_URL + '/sms_status/status',
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure, but you might not have the phone number at the time you make the API request using a messaging service. This request really just queues up the message to be sent.

I would check the message object once it has been sent. You have a status callback URL setup, so you should be able to either [inspect the parameters sent to that URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#statuscallback-request-parameters) or [look up the message from the API using its SID](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#fetch-a-message-resource) and then get the number that was used.